# PHP nested array processing to create date keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a PHP project where I manage data structures (in a `$data` variable) defined like this:

```
array:35 [▼
  "2020-03-16" => array:12 [▼
    "00:00:00" => 17.185
    "02:00:00" => 17.235
    "04:00:00" => 17.25
    "06:00:00" => 16.905
    "08:00:00" => 21.205
    "10:00:00" => 23.47
    "12:00:00" => 24.42
    "14:00:00" => 27.245
    "16:00:00" => 30.94
    "18:00:00" => 30.78
    "20:00:00" => 29.735
    "22:00:00" => 28.64
  ]
  "2020-03-17" => array:12 [▼
    "00:00:00" => 29.985
    "02:00:00" => 32.455
    "04:00:00" => 31.28
    "06:00:00" => 34.33
    "08:00:00" => 29.755
    "10:00:00" => 26.92
    "12:00:00" => 29.72
    "14:00:00" => 28.36
    "16:00:00" => 30.815
    "18:00:00" => 34.605
    "20:00:00" => 34.315
    "22:00:00" => 33.125
  ]
  "2020-03-18" => array:12 [▶]
...
]
```

They come from an external service so I can't modify them in origin.
I need to "rewrite" `$data` so that I finally have something like:

```
array:420 [▼
"2020-03-16 00:00:00" => 17.185
"2020-03-16 02:00:00" => 17.235
"2020-03-16 04:00:00" => 17.25
...
"2020-03-20 00:00:00" => 22.675
"2020-03-20 02:00:00" => 24.67
...
]
```

Could you please tell me a smart way of doing that?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just working with data structures, I found the solution:

```
$cleanData = [];
foreach ($data as $day => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $hour => $value)
        $cleanData[$day.' '.$hour] = $value;
}
```

Some enhancement or any smarter way?
What do you think about the solution?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that code below is simple to understand thanks to one loop :)

```php
$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($inputArray);
$nestedIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator);

$output = [];
foreach($nestedIterator as $nestedKey=>$value) {
    $output["{$iterator->key()} {$nestedKey}"] = $value; 
}
unset($inputArray); // if you need
print_r($output);
```

ofc, two loops often are smart and clear.

Comment: Thanks, but as you say, i feel more comfortable without iterators. Nice solution anyway :)